# msvc2013 with Qt 5 and Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

MSVC2013 has been [released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/10/17/visual-studio-2013-available-now.aspx).  I installed the express version.  I want to use it with Qt 5.1 in Qt Creator.

I uninstalled MSVC2012.  Now when I try and compile Qt Creator says "Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options."

I went to Build and Run and can see that the MSVC2013 compiler is detected.  However under Qt version there is an error.

The path is "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\msvc2012_64_opengl".  At this point I'm guessing what to do.  In the mkspecs directory I copied the win32-msvc2012 to win32-msvc2013 and replaced the qmake.conf file with [this one](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/f1cdd4b2976706c6d9c3166a75afff6ec5856f3d%3amkspecs/win32-msvc2013/qmake.conf).  Then under kits I created a manual version with the same Qt Creator version but set Qt mkspes to win32-msvc2013 but that does not work.

I also tried replacing the old qmake.conf with the new one from the link above in the mkspecs/win32-msvc2012 directory but that made no difference.

Any suggestions on how to setup MSVC2013 with Qt Creator?

Edit: I made some progress.  I deleted the the .pro.user file and reconfigured the project to point to a custom kit which points to the MSVC2013 compiler.  Now when I try and build it says

```
qtmain.lib(qtmain_win.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in main.obj
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this as well. Unfortunately, Qt Creator 2.8.1 (the latest) erroneously recognizes the MSVC2013 toolkit as MSVC2005: http://i.imgur.com/QaLZAFu.png If I specify it manually, the compile fails due to an assertion. If I download the Qt source and try to compile it with MSVC2013, that also results in an error...

Comment: I made some progress but I still get an error.  I edited my question with what I did.

Comment: That is the "compiler fails due to assertion" I was talking about. It doesn't like the version number of the compiler. Because of this, you cannot use precompiled msvc2012. You have to compile with msvc2013, but I was not able to do that due to some more errors...

Comment: Okay, well I guess it will be fixed sometime over the next few months.  Incidentally, I installed QT 5.1.1 last night (over 5.1.0) and now my MinGW works.  My frame rate on my fractal generator went from 75 FPS with MSVC2012 to 90 FPS with MinGW.  At least I can run MinGW now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Qt 5.3](http://qt-project.org/downloads) which came out on May 20 now supports VC 2013.